# Can't call sub dialog from main dialog in BotFramework 4

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I am trying to learn Bot Framework 4, I use the builtin CoreBot template defined here:  https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/generators/dotnet-templates/README.md

I modified the MainDialog.cs so that it will call my custom dialog instead of the included dialog:

Before:

```
return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(BookingDialog), bookingDetails, cancellationToken);
```

After:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> GetIntentStep(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(MyDialog), digitalWorker, cancellationToken);
}
```

The dialogs are injected here in the MainDialog.cs

```
    // Dependency injection uses this constructor to instantiate MainDialog
    public MainDialog(FlightBookingRecognizer luisRecognizer, BookingDialog bookingDialog, ILogger<MainDialog> logger)
        : base(nameof(MainDialog))
    {
        _luisRecognizer = luisRecognizer;
        Logger = logger;

        AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
        AddDialog(bookingDialog);
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            GetIntentStep,
            //IntroStepAsync,
            //ActStepAsync,
            //FinalStepAsync,
        }));

        // The initial child Dialog to run.
        InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
    }
```

Inside of my dialog:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DataTypes.TimexExpression;

namespace CoreBot1.Dialogs
{
    public class MyDialog: CancelAndHelpDialog
    {

        public MyDialog()
            : base(nameof(MyDialog))
        {
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                SayIntentStepAysnc
            }));

            // The initial child Dialog to run.
            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> SayIntentStepAysnc(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var bookingDetails = (Models.MyDialog)stepContext.Options;
            var messageText = $"Your intent is: {bookingDetails.Intent}";
            var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
            if ((bool)stepContext.Result)
            {;

                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(bookingDetails, cancellationToken);
            }

            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

So I put a breakpoint in my dialog and it never hit, however it does hit the MainDialog.cs BeginDialogAysnc call just fine.  I get the error:

```
The bot encounted an error or bug.
To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add MyDialog to dialog list in MainDialog. In you MainDialog  you need to inject MyDialog instance and add it to dialog list using `AddDialog(mydialoginstance);`

Similar to how you have added bookingDialog

Comment: Can you please provide any screenshot or code block for this solution?